# font on visual studio "find symbol results" window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, fonts

I have this very annoying visual issue with the "find symbol results" window on VS 2010. I have few sessions running and on the more recent sessions I have opened the font seems to be very ugly and bold. I was trying to set it to default font by clicking the "Use Defaults" under Options -> Font and Colors but it want change. Can someone please help ,e.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can restore the visual studio to its [default settings](http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2008/11/05/restoring-visual-studio-settings.aspx)

Comment: Think that might do the trick. So far so good. Thanks a bunch for the link.

Comment: I hate this answer (to so many questions), especially when it comes from Microsoft. It might fix a symptom but you're also losing all of your settings. It's as good an answer as "re-install VS", or "your OS", for that matter. If resetting all settings fixes it, surely it must be possible to change only the settings affecting the behavior.

Answer (score 30):

I found that the following seems to work:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment > Fonts and Colours
2. Choose Show settings for: [All Text Tool Windows]
3. For Display items: Plain Text, click the Bold checkbox and click OK
4. Do the same again, but untick the Bold checkbox to revert it.
5. If it doesn't change immediately, try restarting Visual Studio

Mind you, Find Symbol Results isn't really a text window, so maybe setting and resetting any font will work. I don't know.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Thanks anyway, @Rhumborl. See my answer if it didn't work for you other readers.

Comment: +1 this should be the accepted answer... way better than reseting the whole vs to default setting. btw this worked for me on VS2008

Comment: It did not work at first, but after closing and reopening VS, it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I found someone on MSDN who [had a similar issue.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/073bdb48-be42-4c1d-a856-8934ad2749b9/change-colorfont-of-find-symbol-results-tool-window)

I couldn't believe this would fix it, but I went to **Personalization**, and **changed the theme** to Windows 7 Basic, and back to my own Aero theme, and the Find Symbol Results went back to a nice font.

I don't know how this could fix the issue, but it worked for me...

Comment: +1 Restoring fonts to default in VS options used to work for me, but then that stopped working, and now this is the only way that will fox it for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers thus far worked for me. Mr Anderson's looked good except I just wanted the default font, not a custom one and he noted the settings file was nearly empty to begin with so I felt the fix should involve removing settings somewhere, not adding more. What worked was choosing Tools > Options... > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Then in the "Show Settings For:" drop down, I picked "Environment Font". It was set to Automatic. I changed it to a random one (Academy Engraved LTE) and hit the OK button to apply it. This changed fonts all over VS including in the Find Symbols Results window. I changed it back to Automatic and the font and icons went back to normal.

For complete accuracy's sake, at the point that I did this, I had already restored VS to my most recently backed up settings, and then to the default settings before trying this. I'm guessing it would work without those steps but since it changes to the funky font on its own, I don't know how to test it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fix it in VS2008, I assume the same would apply to 2010.

1. Open Tools -> Options -> Expand Environment -> Fonts and Colors
2. Click "Use Defaults"
3. Click OK

This restores it every time for me, no idea why it suddenly changes either.

Comment: It seems to need to be changed to something else then changed back. See my answer if this doesn't work or if you don't want to lose your custom font settings (@sethflowers)

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem again today and followed my own instructions above with complete success. The 'Find Symbol Results' pane updated on the fly.

Now, one thing that might be why it works for me and not for others. I previously took a look at the saved settings file and worked out how the customised Font and Colour settings were saved.

Out of the box, there's no customisation and therefore this XML node is pretty empty. This is the default XML node from an old saved settings

```
<Category name="Environment_FontsAndColors" Category="{1EDA5DD4-927A-43a7-810E-7FD247D0DA1D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_FontsAndColors" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
    <FontsAndColors Version="2.0">
        <Categories/>
    </FontsAndColors>
    <PropertyValue name="Version">2</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

After making customisations, they show up here, like this

```
<Category name="Environment_FontsAndColors" Category="{1EDA5DD4-927A-43a7-810E-7FD247D0DA1D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_FontsAndColors" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
    <FontsAndColors Version="2.0">
        <Categories>
            <Category GUID="{B20C0001-0836-4535-A5E8-96E595B1F094}" FontName="Monaco" FontSize="7" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No">
                <Items/>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
    </FontsAndColors>
    <PropertyValue name="Version">2</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

The problem is, the VS2010 Font and Colour settings panel doesn't list the Find Symbols panel so you can't set the font, but there is a way to set it manually.

There is another XML node that defines some behaviour of Environment_FindSymbols. It has a GUID that you can use to create the Category node defining the the panels Font and Colour.

This is the node to find. Make a note of the Category= GUID value ... probably the same for all VS2010 installations.

```
<Category name="Environment_FindSymbol" Category="{C93260BC-0C07-484a-8188-6F4763BD7FD4}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_FindSymbol" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
    <PropertyValue name="FindOptionsIsExpanded">false</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="LookinReferencesIsChecked">true</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="MatchCaseIsChecked">false</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="Type">2</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="SelectedScope">{B1BA9461-FC54-45B3-A484-CB6DD0B95C94}</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="SelectedScopeSubScope">0</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

Using the noted Category= GUID value "{C93260BC-0C07-484a-8188-6F4763BD7FD4}" create a Category node for the FontAndColors node.

e.g.

```
<Category GUID="{C93260BC-0C07-484A-8188-6F4763BD7FD4}" FontName="Monaco" FontSize="7" CharSet="0" FontIsDefault="No">
    <Items/>
</Category>
```

Set it with the FontName and FontSize of your choice. Probably best to customise another pane to get an example node.

Now add this new node to the other

Remember, this is XML, so you have to make sure the start and end tags match. If you're starting with the saved settings from an out of the box installation, then the tag  needs to be changed to  and its between these tags that you insert the new node you create from the Environment_FindSymbols GUID.

Here's an example for you to use. change Monaco to some font you have installed on your machine.

```
<Category name="Environment_FontsAndColors" Category="{1EDA5DD4-927A-43a7-810E-7FD247D0DA1D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_FontsAndColors" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
    <FontsAndColors Version="2.0">
        <Categories>
            <Category GUID="{C93260BC-0C07-484A-8188-6F4763BD7FD4}" FontName="Monaco" FontSize="7" CharSet="0" FontIsDefault="No">
                <Items/>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
    </FontsAndColors>
    <PropertyValue name="Version">2</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

Once this is in the a saved settings, you can import them and the Find Symbol Result pane will appear in the font of your choice. Then the next time the issue of it appearing in a fugly font, just do the export/import and this new XML node will remain until you manually remove it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I even copied the Node's GUID to make sure I was setting the font for the right category. I tried several fonts at different sizes, all with no effect. I tried restarting visual studio after the import, with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've managed to reset the font on the "Find Symbols" panel in VS 2010. My panel had somehow changed to Helvetica or some other larger bolder non anti-aliased fugly font.

Based on the instructions to Export/Import and Reset settings, I took a different approach. I Exported then re-imported my settings and there's no need to close the DevEnv and restart with command line /reset option or loose any environment settings you've taken time to setup.

During export/import, when you see the Yellow triangled Exclamation symbol, just ignore the warning and tick everything as this is just for local machine and personal use - they warn of intellectual property (exporting) and harmful side effects (importing), which I guess is true if you're going to share the files.

Hope this helps.

Cheers
Mr A

Comment: I have the bold font issue described in the question, and this did not help, although it sounded promising

Comment: see my new reply above or below (Sept 6 '12 at this **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12304248/1037885)** ). Added it as a reply answer to maintain some decent text formatting.

Comment: @heiserman, as well as doing what Mr Anderson suggested, I reset all the Font/Color settings to default in between export/import (one-by-one, it was painful, if it happens again I'll take the time to work out which one actually does the reset). Note that I only exported/importer Font/Color settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself.
For me, the solution was:

1. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
2. Show settings for: Execution Plan
3. Set font and size to what most other windows are using. In my case, that was converting from 10-point Courier New to 9-point Consolas.